# KnowledgeSyncProvider class

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework, synchronization

Does anybody know where to find documentation, howtos, tutorials, etc., on how to extend the KnowledgeSyncProvider class. This class in new with the Microsoft Sync Framework 2.0 CTP. It comes with a sample, but we were not able to find a big picture documentation of this class, besides the absolutely useless MSDN reference documentation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The KnowledgeSyncProvider class seems to have been in the Microsoft Sync Framework 1.0 already. There is a sample here [How to: Configure N-Tier Peer-to-Peer Synchronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc807255.aspx)

The SyncSDK ([1st link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=89adbb1e-53ff-41b5-ba17-8e43a2e66254&displaylang=en) Zanoni provided) comes with a sample application the [Managed NTFS Provider Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902837.aspx). And the MyStore.cs file has some inline documentation too.

There is the [Pro Sync Framework](http://books.google.de/books?id=g2A6FiSXpHkC&pg=PA225&dq=KnowledgeSyncProvider&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3) book on google books (it think they handle the 1.0 version). Of course some pages are missing but I guess you can figure out some anyway. And the [source-code for the book](http://www.apress.com/book/downloadfile/4186) samples is available too

Answer (score 1):

Inherit the class:
public abstract class KnowledgeSyncProvider : SyncProvider

---

There are some links could be helpful:

Microsoft Sync Framework 2.0 CTP2

- http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=89adbb1e-53ff-41b5-ba17-8e43a2e66254&displaylang=en

and

Microsoft Sync Framework 2.0 CTP (October 2008) Documentation

- http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=A3EE7BC5-A823-4FB4-B152-9E8CE9D5546F&displaylang=en

Comment: Hi, Zanoni. Thanks. The documentation does in fact come with an howto, but it is unmanaged.